# jquery selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, css-selectors

I have the following code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
 var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
   var toLoad = hash+'.html #content';
   $('#content').load(toLoad)
  }           
 });

 $('#nav li a').click(function(){

  var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
  $('#content').slideUp(2000,loadContent);
  window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
  function loadContent() {
   $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
  }
  function showNewContent() {
   $('#content').slideDown(2000,hideLoader());
  }
  function hideLoader() {
   $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
  }
  return false;

 });

 });
```

thanks to nettuts a really well written concise and powerful piece of coding (in my opinion)

im having issues with the slide up/down it closes fine, but as the height is different in each content section im loading in, it opens to the old height and snaps to the new one, how can i get around this?

also any way to add browser back/forward button functionality? i havent looked at this yet but would probably have to come back here to ask anyway!

Comment: there are already questions here on preserving history with js

Comment: as i said its something i want to get to just thought id throw it in there while im asking a Q, the sliding to the wrong height is my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the new content before the slideDown it should slide down directly to the current content, not the old content. In order to make your back and forward buttons work, you'll want a history plugin. [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) is probably the best in this regard.

Comment: it is loading the new content first, or am i very much mistaken??